# gp function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement

Tags: triggers, partition, greenplum

i got errors when i created the partition tables automatically via trigger which is created in advance.

**enviorment info:**

GP version :4.3.8.1

**error:**

```
NOTICE:  Found 2 data formatting errors (2 or more input rows). Rejected related input data.
ERROR:  function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement (functions.c:135)  (seg13 ZHJK-HADOOP-SLAVE6:40001 pid=19959) (cdbdisp.c:1326)
DETAIL:  
SQL statement "CREATE TABLE T_FM_HISTORYALARM_20160101(CONSTRAINT T_FM_HISTORYALARM_20160101_eventtime_check CHECK (EVENTTIME >= timestamp '20160101000000' AND EVENTTIME < (timestamp '20160101000000' + interval '1 day')))INHERITS (T_FM_HISTORYALARM)"
PL/pgSQL function "history_alarm_partition" line 36 at execute statement
********** 错误 **********

ERROR: function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement (functions.c:135)  (seg13 ZHJK-HADOOP-SLAVE6:40001 pid=19959) (cdbdisp.c:1326)
SQL 状态: XX000
详细:
SQL statement "CREATE TABLE T_FM_HISTORYALARM_20160101(CONSTRAINT T_FM_HISTORYALARM_20160101_eventtime_check CHECK (EVENTTIME >= timestamp '20160101000000' AND EVENTTIME < (timestamp '20160101000000' + interval '1 day')))INHERITS (T_FM_HISTORYALARM)"
PL/pgSQL function "history_alarm_partition" line 36 at execute statement
```

**function code:**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION history_alarm_partition()  
  RETURNS trigger AS  
$BODY$  
DECLARE tbl_name CHARACTER VARYING;  
    tbl_name_parent CHARACTER VARYING := 'T_FM_HISTORYALARM';
    tbl_name_salve CHARACTER VARYING;  
    tbl_year INTEGER;  
    tbl_month INTEGER;  
    tbl_day INTEGER;
    create_tbl_sql CHARACTER VARYING;  
    insert_tbl_sql CHARACTER VARYING;  
    index_sql CHARACTER VARYING;  
BEGIN   
    SELECT date_part('year',NEW.EVENTTIME)  INTO tbl_year;  
    SELECT date_part('month',NEW.EVENTTIME) INTO tbl_month;  
    SELECT date_part('day',NEW.EVENTTIME) INTO tbl_day;
    IF(tbl_month<10)THEN  
        tbl_name_salve=tbl_year||'0'||tbl_month;  
    ELSE   
        tbl_name_salve=tbl_year||tbl_month;  
    END IF;
    IF(tbl_day<10)THEN
        tbl_name_salve=tbl_name_salve||'0'||tbl_day;
    ELSE
        tbl_name_salve=tbl_name_salve||tbl_day;
    END IF;  
    tbl_name=tbl_name_parent||'_'||tbl_name_salve;  

    --判断表 时间分段表是否存在  
    IF ( (SELECT count(relname) FROM pg_class WHERE relname=tbl_name)>0) THEN  
        insert_tbl_sql='INSERT INTO '||tbl_name ||' VALUES(NEW.*)';  
        EXECUTE insert_tbl_sql;  
    ELSE   
        create_tbl_sql='CREATE TABLE '||tbl_name  
        ||'('  
        ||  'CONSTRAINT '||tbl_name||'_EVENTTIME_CHECK'||' CHECK (EVENTTIME >= timestamp '''||tbl_name_salve||'000000''' ||' AND EVENTTIME < (timestamp '''||tbl_name_salve||'000000'' + interval ''1 day''))'  
        ||')INHERITS ('||tbl_name_parent||')';  
        EXECUTE create_tbl_sql;  

        index_sql='CREATE INDEX '||tbl_name||'_EVENTTIME_INDEX ON '||tbl_name||'EVENTTIME';  
        EXECUTE index_sql;  

        insert_tbl_sql='INSERT INTO '||tbl_name ||' VALUES(NEW.*)';  
        EXECUTE insert_tbl_sql;  
    END IF;  
    RETURN NULL;  
END;  
$BODY$  
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

**create trigger code:**

```
create trigger history_alarm_trigger before insert or update on t_fm_historyalarm for each row execute procedure history_alarm_partition();
```

it is ok when the funtion and trigger are executed , but when the values are inserted into the table T_FM_HISTORYALARM , the parent table ,the error occures.

if i execute the create table statmenet :

```
CREATE TABLE T_FM_HISTORYALARM_20160101(CONSTRAINT T_FM_HISTORYALARM_20160101_eventtime_check CHECK (EVENTTIME >= timestamp '20160101000000' AND EVENTTIME < (timestamp '20160101000000' + interval '1 day')))INHERITS (T_FM_HISTORYALARM)
```

it works well.

can you give me some advice?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior; please see point 8) in the [Greenplum Docs](http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4380/ref_guide/feature_summary.html#topic3).

> Triggers are not supported since they typically rely on the use of `VOLATILE` functions.

Comment: Kyle , thank you so much
if so , how can i change to achieve my goal ?
i hope creating the table if it not exits when inserting value to table.

Comment: Are the event times correlated to the current time or predicable in any way? If so, you can run `cron` on some interval, outside of Greenplum, to ensure you always have a partition for new data, created in advance of the data arriving.